# Approximation for a binomial coefficient sequence summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, approximation, entropy

What is a good approximation to
$$\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$ $$\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{(\log k)^2}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}},\quad\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{\sqrt{k}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{{k}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$
as a function of $k,i$ when $i\in\{1,2,\dots,k-1,k\}$?

I am looking to see the asymptotics of
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$ 
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{(\log k)^2}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}},\quad\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{\sqrt{k}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{{k}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$

I simulated in mathematica functions $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{(\log k)^2}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}},\quad\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{\sqrt k}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$ and both seems to initially decrease and then rapidly increases starting around $k=200$ to $300$.

However $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{{k}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$ seems to keep decreasing.

I suspect 
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{(\log k)^a}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}},\quad\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{{\binom{k}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}(i-1)!}{(2^{k^{1/a}}-1-i)\binom{k(k-1)/2}{i}}$$ both to initially decrease and then increase if $a>1$ while they keep decreasing at $a=1$. Is there an easy method to show this?

Comment: Have you tired Stirling's Approximation? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I could not make it work to get needed approximation.

Comment: magnificent question:|

Comment: @Travis. I enjoy what I suppose to be a typo *Have you tired ....*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Maybe I was projecting---when I wrote the comment, I'd just woken up awfully early and couldn't get back to sleep, and so thought I'd trawl the new questions list for a while.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Considering $$S(k)=\sum _{i=1}^k \frac{(i-1)! \binom{k}{i}^2}{\binom{\frac{1}{2} k(k-1) }{i}}$$ I have not been able to establish asymptotics but numerical simulations show that $\log\big(S(k)\big)$ varies almost linearly with $k$.

Based on values computed for $k=100,200,\cdots,2000$ an empirical curve fit has been done using $$\log\big(S(k)\big)=a+b\, k +c \,\log(k)+d\, k\,\log(k)$$ for which all parameters are highly significant. 
$$\{a=2.52691,b= 0.107636,c= -0.534135,d= -0.0000305592\}$$